# export shared library path via several level of crates denedicies

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

In `build.rs` of `level1-sys` crate I have:

```
    let dst = cmake::Config::new(Path::new("somelib"))
        .build()
        .join("build");
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-search=native={}", dst.display());
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=dylib=somelib");
```

then there is `level2` create that deped on `level1-sys`,
and then there is `level3`binary crate.

If I run this `level3` crates via `cargo run` all works fine,
but if I run it by hands it reports:

```
 error while loading shared libraries: libsomelib.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Is there way to find path to `libsomelib.so` from `cargo`?
I need this info for external script that should pack binary.

Obviously I can search in `target` subdirectory,
but I use debug/release/cross compilation and so on thing.
Plus even for concrete variant like `target/release` after several rebuild of `level1-sys` there are several `libsomelib.so` libraries, like:

```
target/release/build/level1-sys-46422ddc8585ba79/libsomelib.so
target/release/build/level1-sys-9daa760ee41fe7b8/libsomelib.so
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55537573/how-to-link-a-dynamic-rust-library-using-only-rustc-and-not-cargo#comment97778955_55537573

Comment: @Stargateur If I do `cargo clean` and `cargo build -v -v` other teammates send me to the hell. Clean build takes ~30 minutes.

Comment: try [`touch build.rs && cargo build -vv`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49077147/how-can-i-force-build-rs-to-run-again-without-cleaning-my-whole-project/55536259#55536259), you all works on the same machine ?

Comment: @Stargateur We use this script a lot during development, so everyone become unhappy if build of package start takes 30 mins on their local machine.

Comment: @Stargateur But this cause rebuild of `level2` and `level3` packages, this is of course not 30 minutes, but 2 minutes also not good. Is any way to avoid rebuild just to find out path?

Comment: do that `build.rs` don't rebuild level2 and level3 packages if they are up to date ? I have no idea how. but at some point this is just a trick to see what cargo do... as you said "If I run this level3 crates via cargo run all works fine, but if I run it by hands it reports:"